# How can i create a xml document based on a schema using php?

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I want to create a xml file from the data given by the users.

I can use simplexml or DOMDocument for creating xml files and even there is an option in DOMDocument to verify the xml document with a schema .

**But what i need is instead of creating nodes and adding values using xml classes, can i create a xml file from the data stored somewhere else in respect with a schema?**

I think in .net there is an option to write into xml from reading from dataset.. But i couldn't find such thing in PHP.

Is that possible and are there any classes for that?

If there are no predefined classes , at least any help on any ways of doing that?

**Edit:**

I'm editing this question because it seems that some of you is not clear about my requirement..

For example, if the schema is

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="formpatterns">
<xs:element name="pan" type="pantype"/>
<xs:element name="name" type="nametype"/>
<xs:element name="fatherName" type="nametype"/>
<xs:group ref="address"/>
<xs:element name="dob" type="xs:date"/>
</xs:schema>
```

and if user gives the data for pan, name, fathername, address, dob then
i need to create the xml document automatically by matching the schema and data.

The schema may change from time to time , so i dont want to edit all the code to create/ change nodes and attributes. I need just to point the new schema , so that the code creates the xml based on that.

Comment: I've build a simple php class that builds xml files, but not sure that's what you're looking for. As Gordon said an UseCase would be usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/moyarada/XSD-to-PHP it compiles PHP bindings from XSD, and then you can serialize PHP classes to XML.

Comment: The project seems to be arrested

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have a simple answer. It can be done with meta programming, but it is going to be long. In fact, the more complicated your XSD is, the longer your code will be. Yet, if you use a simple XSD with primitive xs:* types, it is easy to define a converter from a PHP type into an XML string.

By parsing your XSD you can dynamically create an array, which will look like this hard-coded one:

```
$meta = array(
  'name' => 'xs:string',
  'dob' => 'xs:date'
  );
```

If you user input is something like:

```
$input = array(
  'name' => 'Name',
  'dob' => new DateTime('30 years ago')
  );
```

Then you can produce dynamically that:

```
$output = array(  
  'name' => convert( $input['name'] , $meta['name'] ),  
  'dob' => convert( $input['dob'] , $meta['dob'] )  
  );
```

The key is the convert function. By using the 'instanceof' operator and the 'is_*' functions you can determine the data type of the first argument. So all you have to do is to return an XML escaped string for each of the possible combinations:

```
php string --> xml 'xs:string'  
php DateTime --> xml 'xs:date'
```

...

Then it is straight forward to create your final XML.

Answer (score -1):

I think [this](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/dom.html) should help you if you want to create XML files using PHP's DOM functions

Comment: The article does not mention the word "schema" once. Interesting, but unlikely what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I already user DOMDocument to create nodes but that's not i want.. I want to look for the schema and create them later(for this we can use DOMDocument) . If there are no classes, atleast a hint on doing this will help.